# Create copy button in popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, popup, shopify

I have a discount coupon code popup like in the picture I attached.
[image]
My question is, how do I create a copy function on the "Copy this coupon code" button? So when the user clicks the "Copy this coupon code" then the `123` coupon code will be copied.
I follow this way but it does not work for popups
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

There is an error message: `copyText.select () is not function`

Comment: Can you provide code example containing `copyText.select()` method? Without any example provided it's hard to tell source of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clear the example

```
 <!-- The text field -->
 <input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">

 <!-- The button used to copy the text -->
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Now see in the text field id is given i.e myInput and now the function as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
copyText.select();
document.execCommand("Copy");
alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

Now in function first we get the input text by that id(myInput) and then applied the rest functionality accordingly. Please check in your code that have you used correct id?

Thanks